# Python: One Player Appears Twice Bug

Tags: python, pandas

I'm writing a script in Python to rank players for the upcoming Fantasy Football season based on how they performed last year.  I scrape their data from Yahoo and create Player objects based on the data (one of either QB for quarterback, RB for running back, WR for wide receiver, and TE for tight end).

I then sort the array of all Player objects by each player's calculatePoints() method.  For what it's worth, if a player is suspended for a certain number of games, I discount his projected points by a proportional amount.  E.g. Tom Brady will be out 4 games, so his projected points gets multiplied by 75%.

Anyway, I've completed the script, run it, and check the output (script creates and writes to a file called output.txt).  Here's what I see:

[image]

Positions #36 *and* #37 is Tom Brady.  Obviously this is a bug but I'm really unsure how it's happening.  For what it's worth, I scrape quarterbacks from this link:

```
http://sports.yahoo.com/nfl/stats/byposition?pos=QB&conference=NFL&year=season_2014&timeframe=All&qualified=1&sort=49&old_category=QB
```

Tom Brady only appears once.  I've run just my getAllQBs() method and it returns an array containing two objects for Tom Brady.  So it happens in the method that scrapes the data.  Here's that method:

```
def getAllQBs():
    QBs = []
    table = pd.read_html(requests.get(QB_LINK).content)[5]
    finalTable = table[2 : ]

    for (_, row) in finalTable.iterrows():
        name = row[0]
        team = row[1]
        passingYards = float(row[8])
        passingTouchdowns = float(row[11])
        interceptions = float(row[12])
        rushingYards = float(row[14])
        rushingTouchdowns = float(row[17])
        rushingFumbles = float(row[20])
        if name in SUSPENSIONS.keys():
            newQB = QB(name, team, rushingYards, rushingTouchdowns, rushingFumbles, passingYards, passingTouchdowns, interceptions, gamesSuspended=SUSPENSIONS[name])
            QBs.append(newQB)
        else:
            newQB = QB(name, team, rushingYards, rushingTouchdowns, rushingFumbles, passingYards, passingTouchdowns, interceptions)
            QBs.append(newQB)
        return QBs
```

Any idea why I'm getting a duplicate Tom Brady?

Thanks for the help,
bclayman

Comment: Is there any other player suspended except Tom Brady?

Comment: @Anachor yes, 5 or 6 others but none that are duplicated (other than Brady)

Comment: maybe it was an issue with yahoo sport, everything seems to be fine. earlier it was an error page when I tried to visit qb_link.

Comment: @valentin Yeah, that's possible.  I just re-scraped and got the same issue so it's reproducible :(

Comment: If you throw a debug print statement in each iteration, printing out name or something do you see Tom Brady printed twice?  I.e., is it actually processing a Tom Brady record more than once or is it adding the same Tom Brady object to the `QBs` list twice?